# Save new Variable Value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa-touch

I have a global variable that has a value of zero and then I use this code to change the value and put in a label:

```
- (IBAction)costSST
{
    // add cost to global variable "totalCost"
    float sstCost = totalCost + 3.50;
    self.lblcurCost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",  sstCost];
}
```

However, I dont know how keep the new value of the global variable—in this case 3.50—instead of still 0. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So wait, is totalCost not retaining it's value, or is sstCost not retaining it's value?

Comment: @CodaFi total cost doesnt retain its new value of 3.50

Comment: That's because you aren't setting totalCost, you're setting sstCost.

Comment: @CodaFi i have set totalCost to 0 in my m file but when i do the action costSST i want the value of total cost to change to 3.50

Comment: you mean like totalCost = 3.5;  ?  why isnt that in the code?

Comment: @CodaFi because i want total Cost to equal zero then change to 3.50 and keep that and then i will add another value like 2.50 so it would be 3.50+2.50  but i have to keep in mind that the user may not choose to add 2.50

Comment: Perhaps you're interested in the += operator then.

Comment: @CodaFi ill have a look then thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `totalCost` retain it's value, you have to actually set it's value instead of referencing it in your arithmetic:

```
- (IBAction)costSST
{
    // add cost to global variable "totalCost"  Because of that, sstCost is unnecessary
    totalCost = 3.50f;
    self.lblcurCost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",  totalCost];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using "global variables". Store persistent values in instance variables.